# Methods of Uploading files to apache without webdav or ftp, scp, ssh, telnet or sftp?

Tags: apache-2.2, cgi

The company where I work has a desktop application that uploads files to a site without any of the aforementioned protocols.

They use CGI on the backend, so is it possible that they are uploading the files via a C++ cgi-script?

Is there an Apache module for calling CGI programs? 
(there has to be...what is it?)

Comment: what do you want to achieve? Build a server that accepts the same files? Or upload files automatically to that site? Or upload files manually without using that site? They probably use HTTP POST for sending files (like any website does where there are file upload boxes) and there are tools for all the things I wrote above. I just don't want to write about all of them in my answer :)

Comment: Why do you suspect c++ and not perl, php, python, etc...

Comment: +1 to counter the down vote that somebody gave without any explanation as to their reasoning for the down vote.

Comment: @Zoredache Because everything they do is written in C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apache uses POST and GET to transfer data. It is probably POSTED to apache, which then sends it to the executable which could be C++, PHP, PERL, or any other number of programming languages.

Your question should be "uploading via Apache" - Apache does not contain any files, the filesystem does.

The apache module for cgi is called, surprisingly, [mod_cgi](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_cgi.html).

Comment: Dave, I checked in their configuration and this seems to have something to do with it.  I'll have to read up further on the mod_cgi module.

Answer (score 3):

Start on the webserver where the request is being processed. It could be dwarfs with punchcards shouting over tin can's connected by strings for all anyone here knows. Look at the webserver, and start tracing the request.

Comment: heheh, yes there's a distinct possibility Zak ;)

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm... Why don't you ask them?

Comment: They're too busy.  They told me just to look around, without really explaining anything.

Comment: Nobody's that busy. It took longer to type this that it would take to answer your question, if properly phrased.

Comment: They write everything in C++.  Yes, they're that busy. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can always use [RFC1149](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1149.html) to move bits.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simply automate uploads, use iMacros for Firefox - works great!
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3863